# Why can't vim find syntax.vim on my fresh Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, configuration, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make some basic customizations to vim. All I want is some syntax highlighting, etc. Basically, not just plain text.

My `.vimrc` file consists of 7 lines:

```
backspace=2
syntax on
filetype indent on
set autoindent
set number
colorscheme desert
set nobackup
```

Every time I launch vim, I get these errors and **see no syntax highlighting**:

```
E492: Not an editor command: backspace=2
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

The latter problem just might stem from the fact that I don't have a `/usr/share/vim` folder. I would have thought that this would have been created when I installed vim. So, what do I do now?

Comment: How exactly did you install vim?  What does `dpkg -l | grep vim` say?

Answer (score 10):

First things first, sit back, relax, and take a few deep breaths. Okay, relaxed now?

For the first error, you need:

```
set backspace=2
```

The second one I can only assume occurred becaue you're not using the standard vim that ships with Ubuntu, or your environment has become broken somehow. What you probably need to do is actually *find* the syntax file with something like:

```
find / -name syntax.vim 2>/dev/null
```

and then ensure that your `VIMRUNTIME` environment variable is set correctly for that (for example, if the file was located at `/xyzzy/plugh/syntax/syntax.vim`, then you would set the variable to be `/xyzzy/plugh`).

Comment: `find / -name syntax.vim` could take a very long time to run, and produce a lot of error messages as it fails to read various system directories.

Comment: @Keith, unless you can narrow it down, you'll have to search everywhere. I'll update the answer to get rid of any errors but I would run this as root anyway because I'm either brave or stupid - sometimes it's hard to tell :-)

Comment: Knowing how vim was installed would likely help track down the location of `syntax.vim` more quickly than `find / ...`.  But if `vim` can't find its own files, it's likely they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the first problem. Not difficult as expected. The second is like speaking a different language. I ran that search and it came up empty. You are right, the standard vim was broken (this is part of long series of problems), so I installed vim73 from a download. I would LOVE to get back to the standard version. Is there a way to do that? Otherwise, I have no earthly idea of how to ensure that my VIMRUNTIME environment variable is set correctly. Stuff like this is a good example of my frustration with Linux, but that's another matter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1024973: I'm still running 11.04 but it's probably the case that 11.10 still uses Synaptic for package management. I would start by doing a search within there for vim and possibly re-installing.

Comment: What was broken in the standard Vim? Where and how did you install your own Vim?

Comment: @user1024973 AFAIK by default Ubuntu ships with minimal vim setup (“vim-tiny”): with most features disabled and without runtime files. You have to install full vim version (named just “vim”), this will also pull runtime files (package “vim-runtime”). You can install runtime files with vim-tiny, but I won’t be surprised if you will then discover that syntax support was disabled at compile time and it still won’t highlight anything.

Comment: For the second error, it might be worth trying `unset VIMRUNTIME` before trying to export it. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the first error, you're setting an option. That uses the `set` command, and that's all there is to it.

```
set backspace=2
```

For the second error, you're missing the system file `/usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim`. That means you need to install the package that provides this file. There is a generic method to find out what that package is, for any file provided by Ubuntu. (The same method works on Debian, *mutatis mutandis*.)

On http://packages.ubuntu.com, search the contents of packages for the keyword `syntax.vim`. This [leads](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=syntax.vim&mode=exactfilename&suite=oneiric&arch=any) you to the [vim-runtime](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vim-runtime) package. You can also perform this search on your machine if you install the [apt-file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/apt-file) package, by running the command `apt-file search syntax.vim`.

In this case, you need more than just the `vim-runtime` package. In fact, don't install it now, read on. The default Ubuntu installation only includes a [tiny version of vim](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vim-tiny) that lacks most bells and whistles (it's just meant as a quick way of editing a configuration file). For serious work, you need to install a [full version of vim](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vim). You have a choice of [no GUI](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/vim-nox) or various GUIs. All of the non-tiny versions pull in the usual advanced features such as syntax highlighting (they depend on the `vim-runtime` package).